# Provide second parameter after first parameter calls with argument

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to get the following Javascript:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Using the following Coffeescript:

```
http.createServer app
  .listen app.get 'port', () ->
    console.log 'Express server listening on port'
```

which results in:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port', function() {
  return console.log('Express server listening on port');
```

The problem being that this obviously puts the callback function as the second parameter to `app.get` rather than as the second parameter to `http.listen`.

Comment: The function-calling parentheses are (sometimes) optional, that doesn't mean that you're never allowed to use them, there's nothing wrong with putting them in if it makes the code easier to read and understand or even if you prefer to have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http
    .createServer app
    .listen app.get('port'), ->
        console.log "Express server listening on port #{app.get 'port'}"
```

You just needed to include parentheses around the `app.get` argument.

Note, see http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/ for jQuery approved styling syntax. Not all rules apply to coffeescript, but the method chaining is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Shame these situations aren't entirely uncommon even in the few hours I've started learning CS.